# Negative translateZ breaks block element hover in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I'm trying to put a negative translateZ on a link. In webkit browsers, this works fine, but Firefox breaks the hover / link / event listener functionality, if the value is lower than a magical `-0.1px`.

Notice it's only broken for block elements and when setting `transform-style: preserve-3d;` on the parent element. The link is still focusable, though, as demonstrated in the codepen.

```
<a class="arrow" href="#bla">
  <svg fill="#000000" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M7.41 7.84L12 12.42l4.59-4.58L18 9.25l-6 6-6-6z"></path>
  </svg>
</a>
```

```css
body {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.arrow {
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;

  display: block;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background: white;

  // Breaks hover for values lower than -0.1px
  transform: translateZ(-0.2px);
}

// This should work, but is broken in Firefox
.arrow:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

Example codepen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yXmgZZ?editors=1100

Is this the expected behaviour, is it simply a bug in firefox or am i missing something? What can i do to make it work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `transform: perspective(0px) translateZ(-0.2px);`

Check [**CODEPEN**](https://codepen.io/nimishw/pen/BZXRag)

Comment: Thanks, but your pen is still broken for me. Both in the latest stable of Firefox v54.0.1 and developer edtion v55.0b10
What version are you using?

Comment: I am using older version 46 because I use chrome. Can you please explain broken means ? My codepen isn't working in any browser or not in Firefox. ?

Comment: Hovering the element (and therefore the link and any event listener) is broken in Firefox in at least the described versions. Interesting that it works in older versions.

Comment: @kulturfunker above video is in v46 and I just updated firefox to 54.0.1 and code is not working in it. But when I remove `transform-style: preserve-3d;` codepen is working fine in latest firefox and chrome.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. Yes, this is exactly what i'm looking for. Unfortunately, the preserve-3d is kind of the whole point of the layout i'm doing and therefore not optional..

Comment: @kulturfunker so you want to use preserve-3d ? and don't want to exclude it ?

Comment: yes, exactly. the design i'm working on requires it.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with a different implementation. I ran your codepen and found the same problem. I'm using Firefox 85. By the way, to run your pen properly you have to edit some value, it does not render on first load.